# Does anyone have good resources on 3D procedural generation of terrain or fractal terrain generation?

Tags: opengl, fractals, terrain, procedural-generation

See title.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search for Perlin Noise and you should get some hints for Terrain Generation.

Answer (score 2):

[Libnoise](http://libnoise.sourceforge.net/index.html) has a very nice [terrain example](http://libnoise.sourceforge.net/examples/complexplanet/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

The book Texturing & Modeling: A Procedural Approach by Ebert, Musgrave, Peachey, Perlin, Worley has a couple of chapters about fractals and terrain creation. The book comes with sample code for fBm terrain creation written by Musgrave, using the Perlin noise function. I've used it for teaching as a reasonably simple program that's easy to play with.

Answer (score 0):

Check Iñigo Quilez (expert in this specific field) tutorials here (terrain ray-marching) :
http://www.iquilezles.org/www/index.htm
http://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/terrainmarching/terrainmarching.htm

He also has an awesome WebGL shader editor (shadertoy) and this specific example may also be of interest :
https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XsX3RB